# Pictures are not displaying to anonymous users on Drupal, using ImageField!

Tags: drupal

I have set up a new drupal site, and I have added an Image field to the default content type *story* using CCK and ImageField. This issue is that I can view the images when logged into my admin account, but when I try to view the images when logged out (like most, if not all viewers of this site would be), they don't appear.

I have check permissions and I can't find anything that looks like the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have enabled the content_permissions module (part of the cck package)?

Comment: Yes that is enabled

Comment: Figured it out, thanks, your tip gave me the idea!

Comment: Can you update your question with what you did? It might help others.

Answer (score 2):

The content permissions module creates a new section under User Management -> Permissions -> content_permissions module - ensure anonymous users have permissions to view each of the image or file fields that have been created.